How to properly install and use katex in a nativescript-angular project
After successfully installing and using katex in an angular project, I decided to try it in a mobile app project based on nativescript-angular.
After the installation of katex in the nativescript-angular project, I keep getting the Module ... had no default export error as seen in the screenshot below.

How do I have this resolved?
The project currently run the following packages:
"@nativescript/angular": "^18.0.0"
"katex": "^0.16.11",
"@types/katex": "^0.16.7",

I managed to solve the issue by adding the property "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true to the compileOptions object in the tsconfig.json file.
